# Rails 3: HTTP 406 and blank page on trying to view json in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, controller

I am a little new with Rails and ajax, and I'm encountering the following frustration whilst trying to debug some fairly simple ajax requests in my controllers.

I have the following code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  #format.html { render :json => db_clean_response.to_json }
  format.json { render :json => db_clean_response.to_json }
end
```

When I try to debug this by manually entering the URL and parameters, the controller correctly prepares the response, but Rails responds with `HTTP/406 Not Acceptable` unless I uncomment the `format.html` command. (Note that the `format.html` stuff is just for trying to fix this.)

I *don't* want this function responding with html, as its only for ajax stuff. Besides, Rails responds with the json uglyprinted onto empty html, and I'd like to use a plugin like JSONView to prettify it.

What's going on here? I feel like the desired result is very simple, but something, somewhere is messing it up. When I try to debug ajax I want my browser to pull up the damn json without being lame :-(

Comment: Are you using `?format=js` in your URL when testing this?

Comment: ...or appending .json to your url?

Comment: ^^^^ that solved it... out of curiosity, is it (easy) possible to make it respond as such without the format=json flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that adding `format=json` to the URL parameters does what I want: forces Rails to return json with all the right headers